# Need help completing my error check

Tags: java

I have this assignment to create a postal barcode converter. Which I have a working program with one exception. The error checking I am attempting to do, to limit the barcode to digit conversion to just the : and | characters (as it is required for the program to convert it back into digits). I am unable to figure out exactly how I am able, if at all possible, to limit the characters to those two in any unspecific order. I've tried (!input.hasNext([:][|])); and it has brought me no luck with any variation I have thought of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static String number()
{
    System.out.println("Enter a barcode with using : or | ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!input.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Please Input a correct number");
        System.out.print("Entry: ");
        input.next();
    }
    String input1 = input.next(); 
    return input1;
}
```

Comment: show a sample input to the program that shows the "good" case and the "error" case

Comment: For clarification, do you want the program to ignore everything after a "wrong" character is detected and take what it received up to that point (meaning my string is `::|::||Q::||`, and the program stops at `Q` giving `::|::||`). Or do you simply want it to error out regardless if a non-acceptable character is detected.

Comment: `while (!input.hasNext())` ... luckily you won't get an exception, because you're using `System.in` as source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the regexp you are looking for is `[|:]*`. This means "any number of characters that are one of `|` or `:`".

If there is any character in the input other than a whitespace, that isn't a bar or a colon, it will be rejected. A space or a newline will be considered the end of the token.

If you want to limit the input to exactly 5 characters, you should use `[|:]{5}`. If you want *at least* 5 characters, but no more than 10, the expression is `[|:]{5,10}`, and if you want at least 5 characters, but you don't care how much longer than that, you should use `[|:]{5,}`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have limited it to the code generation that I'm looking for. However, is there another nested while loop I can put in there to double check for the length of the barcode so that it doesn't crash if the user inputs to few barcodes. The assignment requires 5

Comment: @JonathonP. I edited the answer to accomodate for length checks.

Comment: Awesome! I got it fully functional. Thanks so much! Without those tidbits who knows where I'd be with the program. Thanks again! I'd up vote, but it says I need 15 reputation :(.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want to do is something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a barcode with using : or | ");
String barcode = input.next(); // The barcode should not have white space, so don't use nextLine()
while (!barcode.contains("|") && !barcode.contains(":"))
{
    System.out.println("Error: Please Input a correct number");
    System.out.print("Entry: ");
    input.next();
}
// Do whatever with the barcode
```

Basically, you want to prompt the user once to enter a barcode. The input needs to be validated to see if it contains '|' or ':'.  If the input does not contain either character, you want to continue prompting the user to enter a valid input.  Once they enter a valid input, the code will break out of the `while()` loop and will continue normal execution.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be stuck in the loop no matter what I types, I reformatted it and everything. It just continued the loop regardless of what combination of letters numbers, and ":|" combinations I put in there